# Crystal reports - missing fields 

Tags: sql, reporting, crystal-reports

using Crystal reports 10 linked to an excel document.  Would like to pull the dinner field but also pull country and Company name from row that dont have it, this are linked via Bookingref.  Example below.  I've tried sub-reports and supressing unwanted fields but can't get it right.  Also I can't make changes in excel doc as it's 1000+ records, which is exported from an online system weekly.

```
Id  BookingRef  Country CompanyName Surname Forname Dinner
1   001           UK    Company1    John    Andrews 
2   001                             Mary    Jane    1
3   001                             Tom     Andrews 1
4   002     Germany     Company2    Lee     Jones
5   003     Germany     Company3    Peter   Lee     1
6   003                             Sofie   Lee 1
```

Comment: Are you able to pull the dinner field now or are you having an issue with that? How many Companies and Countries do you have to work with? I mean are we talking a few of each or a great many?

Comment: i can pull dinner data fine, just wont be able to sort on Country & Company name which is required.  currently 11200 records and more to come so can't do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

OK I am not sure I understand the full extent of your problem but let's start with the Country and Company name and see if I can get you moving forward. Instead of putting the Country field directly on the report you could use a formula field and do something like this:

```
IF {@BookingRef} = "001" Then
    "UK"
Else IF {@BookingRef} = "002" Then
    "Germany"
Else
    "Unnamed"
```

Now you just put the formula field where the country field used to be and it will put the right country in bases on the BookingRef code. This, however, is only practical if you are working with a small number of Country / Company Names or possibly a big list that never changes although I would caution against the latter.

The other thing you could do is create a table in any database that holds the BookingRef, Company and Country values, link the BookingRef fields from both "databases" and then just drop the fields on your report.

If I am missing the point of your question please be real specific about what it is you are trying to accomplish and what is and is not working in your current solution.

Comment: thanks..ended up writing report without country and immediatly left for a long holiday! that solution wouldn't work because it assumes booking are from unique countries and also the talking about no less tahn 200 counries to code:)